# Selecting substrings contained within a list (without syntax characters)

Tags: python

I am trying to find and format words that are contained in a list.

Below is what I have tried:

```
word_list = ['Penny', 'cat', 'carnival']

example_string= "I took my dog Penny and my cat, to the carnival."

formatted_text = " ".join(["<b>{}</b>".format(word) if word.strip(' , . ; :;\ " ()[]{}') in word_list else word for (i, word) in enumerate(example_string.split(" "))])
```

output:
I took my dog **Penny** and my **cat,** to the **carnival.**

desired output:
I took my dog **Penny** and my **cat**, to the **carnival**.

Basically I want to iterate on every word in the string and format it if the words are in the list, without formatting the punctuation's such as periods, commas, quotes etc. Is there a way to do such?

Comment: so what you want is to check whether word of the string match with words in the list, if yes then add `<b>` before and  `</b>` after the words, and exclude and punctuation's.

Comment: Yes, I want the code to work exactly as in formatted_text except to not format syntax in bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY:-**

```
word_list = ['Penny', 'cat', 'carnival']

example_string = "I took my dog Penny and my cat, to the carnival."

for x in word_list:
    example_string = example_string.replace(x, "<b>" + x + "</b>")

print(example_string)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
I took my dog <b>Penny</b> and my <b>cat</b>, to the <b>carnival</b>.
```

**WHEN VIEWED ON BROWSER:-**

I took my dog **Penny** and my **cat**, to the **carnival**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression that matches on any instance of a word present in `word_list` and replaces it with enclosing bold tags:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(word_list)})")

result = re.sub(regex, r'<b>\1</b>', example_string)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
I took my dog <b>Penny</b> and my <b>cat</b>, to the <b>carnival</b>.
```